# My median maintenance algorithm doesn't work...(Java)

Tags: java, heap

This is a task from a Coursera course Graph Search, Shortest Paths, and Data Structures by Stanford University.The task is to implement a median maintenance algorithm for this particular stream https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_6ec67df2804ff4b58ab21c12edcb21f8_Median.txt?Expires=1481500800&Signature=MY3YWOJaldKZE1Ea8gxGNUe9SybX1q~OZD2htX9hPHxAJ-OB6b-iCWCtpacqBY9g7j9AUoIEzZm56f7iZ6fZWdrrCH4d6c6hMiaCBDlBaliRT7W6AP2XQoqhKcqiKW8OzeKVgDQSf0O0ASqKHkdP0FAjVGfSYirysQPZl6Y8iF8_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A

My code in Java works on a basis of two heaps:the min_heap-the heap in which the elements are smaller as we go from the bottom to the top and the max_heap-the heap in which elements are bigger as we go from the bottom to the top.For the first two stream elements,I put the smaller one in the max_heap and the bigger one in min_heap.Then for every new element,I check if it's smaller than the root of max_heap-if it is, I insert it into the max_heap.If it isn't, I insert it into the min_heap.Then i check the balance of the two heaps-their sizes can't differ in more than one element.If one heap's size is bigger for more than one than the other heap's size,I delete the root of the bigger heap and then I insert it into the smaller heap.Then I check for the median.The median should be the average of the two heap roots if their sizes are equal,or the root of a bigger heap.I increment a variable count by that median,and after ending the stream loop,i print the count modulo 10000.It prints out 9651,when it should print out 1213(for the record,I did increment the count for the first two elements of the stream in a fitting fashion).

For my algorithm,I use two Java classes.The first is the Heap class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private ArrayList<T> items;
    boolean maximum;

    public Heap( boolean max){
        items = new ArrayList<T>();
        maximum = max;
    }

    private void siftUp()
    {
        if(maximum)
        {
            int k = items.size()-1;
            while(k>0)
            {
                int p = (int)(Math.floor((k-1)/2));
                T item = items.get(k);
                T parent = items.get(p);
                if(item.compareTo(parent)>0)
                {
                    T temp = items.get(k);
                    items.set(k, parent);
                    items.set(p, temp);
                    k=p;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int k = items.size()-1;
            while(k>0)
            {
                int p = (int)(Math.floor((k-1)/2));
                T item = items.get(k);
                T parent = items.get(p);
                if(item.compareTo(parent)<0)
                {
                    T temp = items.get(k);
                    items.set(k, parent);
                    items.set(p,temp);
                    k=p;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void insert(T item)
    {
        items.add(item);
        siftUp();
    }

    private void siftDown()
    {
        if(maximum)
        {
            int k =0;
            int l=2*k+1;
            while(l<items.size())
            {
                int max=l,r=l+1;
                if(r<items.size())
                {
                    if(items.get(r).compareTo(items.get(l))>0)
                    {
                        max++;
                    }
                }
                if(items.get(k).compareTo(items.get(max))<0)
                {
                    T temp = items.get(k);
                    items.set(k, items.get(max));
                    items.set(max,temp);
                    k=max;
                    l=2*k+1;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int k =0;
            int l =2*k+1;
            while(l<items.size())
            {
                int min = l,r=l+1;
                if(r<items.size())
                {
                    if(items.get(r).compareTo(items.get(l))<0)
                    {
                        min++;
                    }
                }
                if(items.get(k).compareTo(items.get(min))>0)
                {
                    T temp = items.get(k);
                    items.set(k,items.get(min));
                    items.set(min,temp);
                    k = min;
                    l= 2*k+1;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public T delete()
            throws NoSuchElementException{
        if(items.size()==0)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        if(items.size()==1)
        {
            return items.remove(0);
        }
        T hold = items.get(0);
        items.set(0,items.remove(items.size()-1));
        siftDown();
        return hold;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return items.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return items.isEmpty();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return items.toString();
    }

    public T peek()
    throws NoSuchElementException{
        if(items.size()==0)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return items.get(0);
    }


}
```

And this is the Medheap class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

public class Medheap {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Heap<Integer> max_heap = new Heap<Integer>(true);
        Heap<Integer> min_heap = new Heap<Integer>(false);
        int count = 0;
        int temp = 0;


try{

    URL url = new        URL("https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_6ec67df2804ff4b58ab21c12edcb21f8_Median.txt?Expires=1481500800&Signature=MY3YWOJaldKZE1Ea8gxGNUe9SybX1q~OZD2htX9hPHxAJ-OB6b-iCWCtpacqBY9g7j9AUoIEzZm56f7iZ6fZWdrrCH4d6c6hMiaCBDlBaliRT7W6AP2XQoqhKcqiKW8OzeKVgDQSf0O0ASqKHkdP0FAjVGfSYirysQPZl6Y8iF8_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    for(int i = 0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        int line = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        if(i==0)
        {
            count+=line;
            temp=line;
        }
        else if(i==1)
        {
            if(line<temp)
            {
                max_heap.insert(line);
                min_heap.insert(temp);
                count+=line;
            }
            else
            {
                max_heap.insert(temp);
                min_heap.insert(line);
                count+=temp;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(line<max_heap.peek())
            {
                max_heap.insert(line);
            }
            else
            {
                min_heap.insert(line);
            }
            if(min_heap.size()+1<max_heap.size())
            {
                min_heap.insert(max_heap.delete());
            }
            if(max_heap.size()+1<min_heap.size())
            {
                max_heap.insert(min_heap.delete());
            }

            int median = 0;
            if(max_heap.size()==min_heap.size())
            {
                median =(int)            (Math.floor((max_heap.peek()+min_heap.peek())/2));

            }
            else
            {
                if(max_heap.size()>min_heap.size())
                {
                    median = max_heap.peek();
                }
                else
                {
                    median = min_heap.peek();
                }
            }
            count+=median;

        }
    }
    in.close();


}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(count%10000);
    }

}
```

And this is the text of the programming assignment:

Download the following text file:

Median.txt

The goal of this problem is to implement the "Median Maintenance" algorithm (covered in the Week 3 lecture on heap applications). The text file contains a list of the integers from 1 to 10000 in unsorted order; you should treat this as a stream of numbers, arriving one by one. Letting xi denote the ith number of the file, the kth median mk is defined as the median of the numbers x1,…,xk. (So, if k is odd, then mk is ((k+1)/2)th smallest number among x1,…,xk; if k is even, then mk is the (k/2)th smallest number among x1,…,xk.)

In the box below you should type the sum of these 10000 medians, modulo 10000 (i.e., only the last 4 digits). That is, you should compute (m1+m2+m3+⋯+m10000)mod10000.

OPTIONAL EXERCISE: Compare the performance achieved by heap-based and search-tree-based implementations of the algorithm.

I can't find what's wrong with my algorithm,so please post solutions!!!

Comment: My advice: narrow down the issue, so your question is some relevant code and a couple of sentences. see also [mcve]

Comment: I'm a java novice, but is there a reason, why you implement your own heap class instead of using a data structure from the standard library (like a priority queue?)